# Collect and total up time intervals

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm really new to coding and have been learning Javascript and was wondering if anyone could be kind enough to help me?

So the script below makes a little game that will show you the time between clicks.

I want to learn how to: total up the time it takes in each of the intervals (rounds) into the total time it took to complete the rounds.

and

limit the game to 20 intervals (round)

If anyone has the time to educate me I would be most grateful, I'm told it can be done without an array, is this true?

Thanks

Ben

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Reaction Timer</title>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            body {
              font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            #shape {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: red;
                display: none;
                position: relative; 
            }

            .bold {
                font-weight: bold; 
            } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
        <p>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p>
        <p class="bold">Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
        <p class="bold">Your total time: <span id="totalTime"></span</p>
        <div id="shape"></div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            function totalTimeTaken()  { }
            
            function getRandomColor() {
                var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
                var color = '#';
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
                }
    
                return color;
 
            }
            
            function makeShapeAppear() {
                var top = Math.random() * 400;
                var left = Math.random() * 400;
                var width = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;
                
                if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";       
                }

                document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
                
                document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";
                
                document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
                start = new Date().getTime();
 
            }
            
            function appearAfterDelay() {
                setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000);
            }
            
            appearAfterDelay();
            
            document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
                var timeTotal = 0;
                var numAttempts=0;
                document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
                document.getElementById("timeTakenTotal").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
                appearAfterDelay();
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This just sets a condition that checks if it has been run 20 times.

```js
var startedAt = new Date().getTime();
var start = new Date().getTime();
var timesTaken = 0;
var totalTime = 0;

function totalTimeTaken(value) {
  if (value == "return") {
    totalTime = ((new Date().getTime()) - startedAt) / 1000;
  }
  return totalTime;
}
setInterval(function() { document.getElementById("totalTime").innerHTML = totalTimeTaken("return") + "s"; }, 10);
function getRandomColor() {

  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');

  var color = '#';

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

  }

  return color;

}

function makeShapeAppear() {

  var top = Math.random() * 400;

  var left = Math.random() * 400;

  var width = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";

  } else {

    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";

  }

  document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

  document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";

  document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";

  document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";

  document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";

  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";

  start = new Date().getTime();

}

function appearAfterDelay() {

  setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000);

}

appearAfterDelay();

document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {

  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";

  var end = new Date().getTime();

  var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

  var timeTotal = 0;

  var numAttempts = 0;

  document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";

  if (timesTaken != 20) {
    appearAfterDelay();
    timesTaken += 1;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Reaction Timer</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    #shape {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      display: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>

  <p>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p>

  <p class="bold">Your time: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>

  <p class="bold">Your total time: <span id="totalTime"></span></p>

  <div id="shape"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The total time is working as well!

Comment: Thank you so much;

so what you did here is:
add var timesTaken globally

then

var numAttempts = 0;


added the if 

 if (timesTaken != 20) {
        appearAfterDelay();
        timesTaken += 1;


How does the "numAttempts" work? it doesn't seem to match in withanything else on the page.

Comment: The `numAttempts` was part of your code. You can use that instead of `timesTaken` or just remove it. Also if you want me to help you fix that total time display, please leave a comment.

Comment: Hay yes please, ill be back to it on Monday  morning!  Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it! I've had a total of three days experience of coding and I'm hooked!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the total time is working (if this is how you meant), if not tell me. Great to hear that people like coding!